# How to make a bouncy ball in PyGame, Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a Pong game in python with PyGame, and I want to learn how to make a bouncy ball. I did quite a bit of research and youtube watching but I made NO progress. And it will be useful to know how to make the ball bounce off some shapes drawn with `pygame.draw.rect()` and many other shapes. But please, don't provide the actual code for making a Pong game.

Comment: To begin with I'd recommend figuring out the logic behind something like this *without* any visuals. With only the coordinates and dimensions of the ball and paddles, how would you determine if the ball has collided and then what do you change so it "bounces".

Comment: @dantechguy i really dont know which is why I came to ask :(

Comment: It might be worth searching up existing working pong code, and looking at it to try and understand the logic used in them. It may seem daunting to try figure out what someone else's code does, but being able to do so is also a skill that is pretty important. If you still want a hand just shout and I'll try to whip something up to explain.

Comment: I am trying my best to start completely from scratch

Comment: An answer on here would explain the same concepts any good tutorial will. If you're trying to build something from scratch but can't figure out how, then that might be a sign that you should try to get a more solid understanding before attempting it. Looking at and understanding existing code will help you learn much more than trying to figure it out when you may not know everything you need to :D If you're still confident you want an answer then of course I will, but bear this in mind. Its not cheating in the slightest to learn from someone else's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll work through this explanation thoroughly so don't be surprised if you find some parts obvious.

Now, as I mentioned in my comment, to get a true understanding of whats going on it can be helpful to try and write the logic without any GUI. This places emphasis on your conceptual understanding.

## Concept one: x & y coordinates

Alright, lets begin. When it comes to 2D graphics, in any 2D environment we know that an item's position can be represented by two variables: an `x` and a `y` coordinate. There is no requirement that these variables are specifically `x` and `y`, its just convention, but what *is* important is the idea of having these **two** variables.

By changing these two values in any combination, we can position an item *anywhere* in that 2D world. The same applies to a number line for example, we only need *one* variable to position an item anywhere in that **1**D world.

In this image we can see that the big cross has been positioned in the 2D world (the "2D world" being the graph in this case). The combination of the two variables `x` and `y` being (200, 100) positions the cross at that specific place, and no other combination of these two variables can place it exactly there.

[image: Cross at 200, 100]

This is the first important concept to understand: the idea of a coordinate system. Being able to position items in a 2D space by changing two values. *Or* you could see it as that each position in a 2D space has its own `x` and `y` coordinates, both are accurate.

Again, just as using the letters `x` and `y` is convention, its also convention to picture that the `x` value describes the *horizontal* position and the `y` value describes the *vertical* position. You would typically see that a bigger `x` value is 'more right', and a bigger `y` value is 'more up'. This places the coordinates (0, 0) at the bottom left of such a 2D world.

Not always though, as with this graph and Pygame for example! Pygame sees a bigger `y` value as 'more down', so Pygame's coordinates (0, 0) are in fact at the *top* left of its 2D world (in this case the "2D world" is Pygame's graphical window).

## Concept two: velocity

Its all good and well to be able to position items in a 2D world, but its pretty useless if we can't *move* these items! Now something which is quite relevant here is a basic knowledge of frames. The Pygame window updates itself many times every second, because - well if it didn't then the picture wouldn't change! Every time it updates, its called a **frame**. This is where the term *frames per second* (fps) comes from, essentially telling you how many times it updates every second.

So, lets say we want to move an item *right* (aka increasing the `x` value) in our 2D world (again, this "2D world" in Pygame is the window). How would we go about doing this? If the item is at coordinate (200, 100), to move it right all we need to do is increase the `x` value right? Okay then, lets see what it would look like if we increased the big cross' `x` value by 100 (so its moving right).

[image: Moving a big cross right]

But if we did this all in just one frame, then it would essentially just teleport 100 to the right! And *I* wouldn't call *that* 'moving'. If I think of something moving, then its more of a gradual shift from one position to another.

Hmm, okay.. so how about instead of moving it 100 all in one go, we move it by 5, *twenty times*. 20 * 5 is still 100, so by the end it will still have moved 100, but in this case, because we're spreading out the movement into twenty blocks of 5, it *appears* more gradual to the human eye.

More specifically, we can move the item by 5 every frame, *for twenty frames*. Since the window updates a certain number of frames every second (typically this can default to 30 or 60 frames per second), there is a small time gap between each frame, and by only moving by 5 each frame, we end up *spreading out* the movement of 100 from an instant to just under a second.

All this time, we've been talking about moving this item by 5 every frame, but to be honest it could be anything! It could move by 1 every frame, it could move by -5 every frame (so backwards), it could move by 2.5 every frame (so 5 in two frames). This value, this *amount moved per frame*, can be called the **velocity**. The higher the velocity (so the more distance moved every frame), the faster the item appears to be moving, since its covered more distance in the same amount of time.

Now we've only thought about moving the item right (and technically left too by moving right a *negative* amount), therefore we can call this *amount moved horizontally per frame* the **`x velocity`**. The same also applies to moving the item up and down, so the *amount moved vertically per frame* being the **`y velocity`**.

```py
x = 200
y = 100

x_velocity = 5
y_velocity = 0

while True:
    # each loop can be thought of as one frame
    x += x_velocity
    y += y_velocity

    # ... other pygame code stuff ...
```

In the above code, each frame the item's x value increases by 5, so we can say that the **`x velocity`** is 5. As the y value does not change, the **`y velocity`** is 0. The `x` and `y` velocities are in essence the horizontal and vertical *speed* of the item. The greater the value, the faster it moves in that axis, and if its negative then it moves in the opposite direction.

This is the second important concept to understand: the idea of velocity. The ability to move an item's position by changing its coordinates every frame, and the amount it moves (or "changes by") is known as the velocity.

## Concept three: bouncing

At the moment, so far we can move an item gradually across the screen, by setting `x` and `y` velocities and changing the `x` and `y` values by these velocities each frame. So what happens when we hit a wall? Well the item should bounce right? In the current state the item would simply continue off the edge window.

Well lets take a specific example shall we? If the ball has an `x velocity` of -5, and `y velocity` of 0 (so its moving left 5 per frame), and it hits the left wall, what should happen? Well since we know we need to make the ball move backwards, we change its direction by negating the velocity (turning it from -5 to 5). The ball hit the *left* wall, so it should bounce horizontally, so the `x velocity` should be negated (so its now moving right).

Okay, so we know *how* to make it bounce horizontally, but how do we know *when* it needs to bounce?

[image: Empty graph]

As soon as the item moves left of the left wall (so we know it needs to bounce), we can see that its `x` value is negative (aka `<0`). So, I think it would be pretty safe to deduce the following rule:

```py
if x < 0:
    x_velocity = abs(x_velocity)
```

The `abs()` function makes the number you give it positive. So `abs(-5) -> 5`, but also `abs(5) -> 5`. So what the rule above actually means is: "when the item's `x` value is less than 0 (so its passed the left wall), make its `x velocity` positive (make it move right, causing it to 'bounce' )".

Following the same logic, we can apply the same to the `y` value:

```py
if y < 0:
    y_velocity = abs(y_velocity)
```

The next question to naturally arise is about the bottom and right walls. Since how can we know when the item has passed those? Looking at the picture below might give us some insight:

[image: Ball passed right wall]

We can visually see that the right wall is at `x` 500, and the bottom at `y` 400. In this case the window size is 500x400. Since the left wall is at `x` value 0, we know that the right wall *must* be at the `x` value of the window's width. And the same for the bottom wall too, since the top wall is at `y` value 0, the bottom wall must be at the `y` value of the window's height. Therefore we can complete the bouncing code for all 4 walls to make this:

```py
# left wall
if x < 0:
    x_velocity = abs(x_velocity)

# top wall
if y < 0:
    y_velocity = abs(y_velocity)

# right wall
if x > width:
    x_velocity = -abs(x_velocity)

# bottom wall
if y > height:
    y_velocity = -abs(y_velocity)
```

The reason for `-abs()` is because at the right and bottom walls, we need to make the ball bounce left/up respectively, and in each of these cases the corresponding `x` or `y` velocities are both always negative. We first make them always positive with `abs()`, and then negate that with `-` to make `-abs()` be always negative.

We can combine this with our earlier velocity code to make the pseudo-python-code for a ball bouncing inside 4 walls:

```py
x = 200
y = 100

x_velocity = 5
y_velocity = 5

while True:
    x += x_velocity
    y += y_velocity

    # left wall
    if x < 0:
        x_velocity = abs(x_velocity)
    
    # top wall
    if y < 0:
        y_velocity = abs(y_velocity)
    
    # right wall
    if x > width:
        x_velocity = -abs(x_velocity)
    
    # bottom wall
    if y > height:
        y_velocity = -abs(y_velocity)
```

Being able to understand how to manipulate an item's velocity to simulate bouncing is the trickiest part so far, but just as important for the final product.

## Concept four: paddles

So far we've just implemented some generic ball bouncing rules, so how about we start on something specifically pong-like? The next thing missing is the paddles, so lets think about how we can make those work.

Below I've pictured the Pygame window, and with the red lines being where the paddles could potentially be.

[image: Window with paddles]

First off, lets use our new knowledge to figure a few things out about these paddles. Say, for example how we're going to be keeping track of where they are! We know that we can store an item's position using two values, one of which we'll be using here. The `y` value tells us the vertical position (or "distance from the top") for an item.

So, looking at the picture above, we can see that the left paddle is right at the top. Its "distance from the top" is zero!, *sooo* that means that we could say that the left paddle has a `y` value of 0. And the right paddle, its 100 away from the top, so it has a `y` value of 100. Simple stuff!

*But*, thats not all. Before when we were talking about a single point, it didn't have any height like the paddles do! And in this case the paddles look to be 200 tall. But here's a question: what's the *maximum* `y` value these paddles can have? So, if the paddles are 200 tall, and the height of the window is 400, then 200 above 400 means 400 - 200 which means the max is 200!

Okay, so we've figured out *how* to store the paddles vertical position (the `y` value), *and* the maximum `y` value it can have! (If there was no maximum, then it would disappear off the bottom!) The next thing to do is how to move it. Lets say that as long as we hold the `W` key, the left paddle should move up by 5 (so -5 from `y`), and holding the `S` key should move the paddle down by 5 (so +5 to `y`).

We're going to want to check which keys are pressed every frame, and then move the paddle by 5 in the direction. Remember from before how the *amount moved every frame* is known as the **velocity**? Well the same applies here! The only difference is that the paddle only moves when the key is pressed, but it still applies here: since the paddle moves by 5 each frame (when a key is pressed), the paddle's velocity will be 5! Obviously this can be anything, but 5 sounds good to me. Lets take a look at some pseudo-python-code:

```py
# start the paddle at the top
paddle_y = 0
paddle_velocity = 5

# each loop is one frame
while True:
    if key_pressed('w'):
        # we are subtracting so it moves upwards
        paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('S'):
        paddle_y += paddle_velocity
```

*Oh wait!!* I totally forgot about the limits! Right now with this code the paddles can move off the screen.. whiiich sucks. Okay, well we know that the distance from the top *can't* be less than zero, so the range is `0 to window_height - paddle_height`. We just have to make sure it doesn't reach outside those values! If the `y` value ever *does* go beyond, then we'll just move it back to the limit. Take a look at the updated code which handles this:

```py
# start the paddle at the top
paddle_y = 0
paddle_velocity = 5
paddle_height = 200

# each loop is one frame
while True:
    if key_pressed('w'):
        # we are subtracting so it moves upwards
        paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('S'):
        paddle_y += paddle_velocity

    # limits the minimum y to 0
    if paddle_y < 0:
        paddle_y = 0
    # limit the maximum y to keep it on the screen
    if paddle_y > (height - paddle_height):
        paddle_y = (height - paddle_height)
```

The function `key_pressed()` is just one I made up for demonstration purposes, but there should be something similar in Pygame.

Cool beans, we've got it moving! The next part of paddles is making the ball bounce off them. Looking at the picture, we can see that the paddles don't really have a width.. if anything they're sort of *part* of the wall in way. In normal pong the side walls are out-of-bounds, so the paddles could be seen as the part of the wall which *aren't* out of bounds. A small, moving portion of the wall which is bounces the ball and is not out-of-bounds.

Lets do a few things to the code we've got so far. First off lets combine the ball and paddle code, we'll change the left and right walls to be out-of-bounds, and we'll add controls for a second, right paddle with `O` and `L` for controls:

```py
ball_x = 200
ball_y = 100
ball_x_velocity = 5
ball_y_velocity = 5

left_paddle_y = 0
right_paddle_y = 0
paddle_velocity = 5
paddle_height = 200

# each loop is one frame
while True:

    # BALL
    ball_x += ball_x_velocity
    ball_y += ball_y_velocity

    # left wall
    if x < 0:
        out_of_bounds()
    
    # top wall
    if y < 0:
        ball_y_velocity = abs(ball_y_velocity)
    
    # right wall
    if x > width:
        out_of_bounds()
    
    # bottom wall
    if y > height:
        ball_y_velocity = -abs(ball_y_velocity)

    # PADDLES
    if key_pressed('w'):
        left_paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('S'):
        left_paddle_y += paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('O'):
        right_paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('L'):
        right_paddle_y += paddle_velocity

    if left_paddle_y < 0:
        left_paddle_y = 0
    if left_paddle_y > (height - paddle_height):
        left_paddle_y = (height - paddle_height)
    if right_paddle_y < 0:
        right_paddle_y = 0
    if right_paddle_y > (height - paddle_height):
        right_paddle_y = (height - paddle_height)
```

Nice! The rundown of of the next step is: if the ball hits either left or right wall, then only bounce the ball if its inside the paddle. The next natural question is "how do we know if the ball is inside the paddle?".

[image: Window with paddles]

Looking at this picture again, specifically at the right paddle, for the ball to bounce off of the right paddle it needs to be between its top and bottom point. So we need to compare the `y` values for the ball, and the paddle's ends. The paddle's top is just its `y` value, and the paddle's bottom is its `y` value + its height. So for the ball to be inside the right paddle, the following must be true:

```py
if (ball_y > right_paddle_y) and (ball_y < right_paddle_y + paddle_height):
    # bounce!
```

Lets add that bouncing code for both left and right paddles in shall we?

```py
ball_x = 200
ball_y = 100
ball_x_velocity = 5
ball_y_velocity = 5

left_paddle_y = 0
right_paddle_y = 0
paddle_velocity = 5
paddle_height = 200

# each loop is one frame
while True:

    # BALL
    ball_x += ball_x_velocity
    ball_y += ball_y_velocity

    # left wall, only bounce if its inside the left paddle
    if x < 0:
        if (ball_y > left_paddle_y) and (ball_y < left_paddle_y + paddle_height):
            ball_x_velocity = abs(ball_x_velocity)
        else:
            out_of_bounds()
    
    if y < 0:
        ball_y_velocity = abs(ball_y_velocity)
    
    # right wall, only bounce if its inside the right paddle
    if x > width:
        if (ball_y > right_paddle_y) and (ball_y < right_paddle_y + paddle_height):
            ball_x_velocity = -abs(ball_x_velocity)
        else:
            out_of_bounds()
    
    if y > height:
        ball_y_velocity = -abs(ball_y_velocity)

    # PADDLES
    if key_pressed('w'):
        left_paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('S'):
        left_paddle_y += paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('O'):
        right_paddle_y -= paddle_velocity
    if key_pressed('L'):
        right_paddle_y += paddle_velocity

    if left_paddle_y < 0:
        left_paddle_y = 0
    if left_paddle_y > (height - paddle_height):
        left_paddle_y = (height - paddle_height)
    if right_paddle_y < 0:
        right_paddle_y = 0
    if right_paddle_y > (height - paddle_height):
        right_paddle_y = (height - paddle_height)
```

Neato!! We've added working paddles now :D The game technically works, but there is one improvement left to add.

Comment: I just upvoted tons of your answers and question so you have a higher reputation now :D your help was great

Comment: As much as I appreciate it, you should only upvote if you find it genuinely helpful, and SO has systems to prevent against mass upvoting. The gesture is taken kindly nonetheless! :D

Comment: Oh ok but your reputation has gone down. Why?

Comment: Because SO has [serial voting detectors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) which reverse cases such as this one, where they revoke mass upvotes.

Comment: oh ok i understand

Comment: Just added the penultimate concept to my answer, and the fifth one isn't even necessary